# Spark Scala groupBy(cols).agg( 20 sum up functions), how to use map to simplify 20 agg functions?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, aggregate-functions

Let's say A list of `Seq("a", "b", "c")` and eventDF,

```
eventDF.groupBy("date").agg(sum("a"), sum("b"), sum("c")) works fine.
```

Another case is I have a list with 26 columns

```
val alpha = Seq("a", ... "z").
```

I mean it's too messy to list all 26 sum() aggregation func.

what i try to do is:

```
def sumAgg = (colName: String) => sum(colName)

eventDF.groupBy("date").agg(alpha.map(sumAgg(_))),
```

it seems agg() can't take a Seq list as the parameters.....

Answer (score 2):

Try with `.map` to get all the **sum aggregation** for all the columns and then convert as `toMap`

**`Example:`**

```
val df =Seq((1,2,3), (3,4,5),(1,1,1), (3,2,2))
        .toDF("A", "B", "C")

val sum_expr=Seq("B","C").map((_ -> "sum")).toMap

df.groupBy('A).agg(sum_expr).show(false)
```

**`Result:`**

```
+---+------+------+
|  A|sum(B)|sum(C)|
+---+------+------+
|  1|     3|     4|
|  3|     6|     7|
+---+------+------+
```

---

***Update:***

```
val sum_alias=Seq("B", "C").map(c=>sum(c).as(s"sum_$c")) //returns List with alias for column
```

As `.agg()` accepts String,Map,Column so `.head` returns `string` and `tail` returns list and convert as `string` `use : _*`.

It would be easier to understand if we use **`eclipse maven project`**(intellisense) to get all the functions and params accepted by functions.

[image]

```
df_ppp.groupBy('A).agg(sum_alias.head,sum_alias.tail: _*).show(false)
```

**`Result:`**

```
+---+-----+-----+
|A  |sum_B|sum_C|
+---+-----+-----+
|1  |3    |4    |
|3  |6    |7    |
+---+-----+-----+
```

Comment: This works, Thanks. i also find:  df.groupBy('A).agg(Seq.head, Seq.tail:_*) works...  so it's taking the parameters out and fill it in Agg, i am kinda confused what agg() really takes.... and do you know any other solutions besides toMap and Seq.head, tail methods?     and also, if i want to rename each loop columns,  how to put . as("agg_a") in this Map(String, String) methods

Comment: Yeah, this is what i figured out before, using head and tail. and i also checked the official documents about the agg(), it can take 4 diffierent forms. one of them is column*. but why can't i do sum_alias.map(col): _* to pass the column names and i can only do head and tail?